# How to make the points of a scatterplot semi-transparent with SPSS?

Tags: opacity, scatter-plot, spss

I've made this graph with the SPSS base default scatterplot : I used the "Bin-element" and "Marker Size" options to regroup superposed points and make them easier to read. Here it is :
http://imageshack.com/a/img902/8746/pTRzJV.jpg

But I would like to get a graph that looks like this one :
http://espnfivethirtyeight.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/morris-feature-skepticnflweek2-2.png

The points of this graph are utilizing semi-transparency. I tried to find some stuff about opacity or semi-transparency, and I found only this ressource :
http://andrewpwheeler.wordpress.com/2012/06/17/visualization-techniques-for-large-n-scatterplots-in-spss/

Unfortunately, I don't understand how to do it... Could you please help me ?

By the way, do you know whether this graph has been made with SPSS or rather R ? Which tool would be the best for this kind of graphs ?

Thank you !

Comment: The chart by the 538 blog I would guess is edited in a vector graphics program (like Illustrator). It could be first made and then later edited in any stat packages (Nathan Yau in *Visualize This* has examples of doing that.) Note in my blog post you linked to I have the code to make all the graphs at the end of the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a brief example. So first I will make some fake data.

```
INPUT PROGRAM.
LOOP ID = 1 TO 10000.
END CASE.
END LOOP.
END FILE.
END INPUT PROGRAM.
COMPUTE X = RV.NORMAL(0,1).
COMPUTE Y = RV.NORMAL(0,1).
```

Now, you *cannot* generate opacity within the GUI as far as I'm aware - you **need** to specify it in syntax. So go ahead and go through the *Graph Builder* GUI dialogue, specify the scatterplot you are interested in, and then *paste* the syntax. Here is what the default produces for me plus the graph (with my particular chart template).

```
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=X Y MISSING=LISTWISE REPORTMISSING=NO
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: X=col(source(s), name("X"))
  DATA: Y=col(source(s), name("Y"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("X"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Y"))
  ELEMENT: point(position(X*Y))
END GPL.
```

[image]

Now you will need to edit the options on the second to last line, the `ELEMENT` statement. I am going to do two things; 1) make the points smaller and 2) make the exterior line of the points semi-transparent. Here is the code and the resulting graph follows.

```
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=X Y MISSING=LISTWISE REPORTMISSING=NO
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: X=col(source(s), name("X"))
  DATA: Y=col(source(s), name("Y"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("X"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Y"))
  ELEMENT: point(position(X*Y), size(size."2"), 
           transparency.exterior(transparency."0.9"))
END GPL.
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your answer until right now. Thank you very much for your answer and your comment.